# Makefile new variable based on other variables

Tags: variables, makefile

I am new to Makefiles and have a question about variables in Makefiles.

Let say, I have

```
dirs := $(shell PERL5OPT="" get-list.pl)
```

where ,
get-list.pl say returns a b c d

Now I want to make some new variables dirs_a , dirs_b , dirs_c etc.

How I am doing this currently is :

```
dirs := $(shell PERL5OPT="" get-list.pl)

dirs_$(var) := $(shell PERL%OPT="" some-other-perl-file.pl $(var))

define new-var
$(foreach var,$(dirs),$(dirs_$(var)))
endef

final-target:
    $(new-var)
```

This does not seem to work and no parameter is passed to some-other-perl-file.pl . Can someone point out what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: So you want to create one variable that contains all dirs or one variable per dir?

Comment: I want to create one variable per directory. Basically I need 1 variable per directory so I am creating different variables since I am not sure we can have something like an array in Makefile instead of different variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
_dirs := $(shell PERL5OPT="" get-list.pl)
dirs=$(_dirs:%=dir_%)
```

This should fix it.

It will make:

> a b c d

to

> dir_a dir_b dir_c dir_d

Comment: I am not sure if I get it correctly , but I want to make the new variables dirs_a , dirs_b etc whose value should be as returned by some-other-perl-file.pl .

Comment: dirs=$(_dirs:%=dir_%)

Has a typo in it. It should be:

    dirs=$(_dirs:%=dirs_%)

Basically what that line does is, it iterates each element in _dirs and transforms that element with the rule % -> dirs_%. Where % is what what the element was before. So 'a' would become 'dirs_a'.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification but thats not what I am looking for.